# Mongoose schema validator type error with TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

So I have this mongoose schema definition for a user for my application and I have a validate function for the email attribute, however typescript is giving me a type error for the email attribute and I have no Idea what it means or how to fix it considering that I also have an email attribute for the corresponding interface.

```
import { Schema, model } from "mongoose";
import { hash, genSalt } from "bcryptjs";
import { Model } from "mongoose";
import { isEmail } from "validator";

interface userI {
  name: string;
  email: string;
}

// ignore this
interface userMethodsI {}

type UserModel = Model<userI, Record<string, never>, userMethodsI>;

const userSchema = new Schema<userI, UserModel, userMethodsI>({
  name: {
    type: String,
  },

  // type error when hovering over 'email'
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "email must be provided"],

    // when 'validate' is removed, there are no type errors
    validate: {
      validator: isEmail,
      message: `please provide a valid email address`,
    },
    unique: true,
  }
});
```

type error when hovering over email attribute in the userSchema:

```
Type '{ type: StringConstructor; required: [true, string]; validate: { validator: (str: string, options?: IsEmailOptions | undefined) => boolean; message: string; }; unique: true; }' is not assignable to type 'SchemaDefinitionProperty<string, userI> | undefined'.
  Types of property 'validate' are incompatible.
    Type '{ validator: (str: string, options?: IsEmailOptions | undefined) => boolean; message: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Function | RegExp | [RegExp, string] | [Function, string] | ValidateOpts<string> | ValidateOpts<string>[] | ... 6 more ... | undefined'.
      Types of property 'validator' are incompatible.
        Type '(str: string, options?: IsEmailOptions | undefined) => boolean' is not assignable to type 'ValidateFn<string> | LegacyAsyncValidateFn<string> | AsyncValidateFn<string> | ValidateFn<Mixed> | LegacyAsyncValidateFn<...> | AsyncValidateFn<...> | undefined'.
          Type '(str: string, options?: IsEmailOptions | undefined) => boolean' is not assignable to type 'ValidateFn<string>'.
```

Moreover, when I remove the validate attribute in the 'email' object, there are no type errors. Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

So the type error goes away when I change the validator to be a function that calls the 'isEmail' function.

i.e. from this:

```
email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "email must be provided"],

    // when 'validate' is removed, there are no type errors
    validate: {
      validator: isEmail,
      message: `please provide a valid email address`,
    },
    unique: true,
  }
```

to this:

```
email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "email must be provided"],

    // when 'validate' is removed, there are no type errors
    validate: {
      validator: (email: string) => isEmail(email) ,
      message: `please provide a valid email address`,
    },
    unique: true,
  }
```